# What are the security flaws of exposing OAuth access_token to a user?

Tags: api, security, oauth

The title may sound stupid, but I couldn't find a better way to express myself.

I have an API using OAuth2 server. This API is a backend service for my mobile application, but I will also provide it to thirdy party applications.

I also have a login method, which is used to authenticate the user with email and password and it returns the access_token to this user for my mobile application.

So, whenever you make a `POST /api/v1/users/auth` with `email` and `password`, you will get a 'full-access' token, which have all scopes available. I don't think there's a big flaw here because whoever holds the user's credentials may access the application through the web interface and do whatever he wants.

But still, it's weird to think that anybody can get a access_token from an existing application, because in normal OAuth proccess, only the proper application can fetch a access_token from the server. But I don't even think that Oauth2 was designed to client-exposed applications, like desktop, javascript, etc.

Is there a better way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any worries as long as you're communicating via https and your javascript is secure/stable.

Otherwise you run the following risks:

1) Credentials being stolen by code injected into your page via an XSS vulnerability.

2) An eavesdropper with the ability to read packets could steal the credentials.

3) Software such as  "FaceNiff" that sniffs security tokens, such as facebook & google, and allows them to login in with any user's account who is connected to that WIFI.

4) Granting privileges to code that might abuse those privileges either intentionally or by acting on behalf of yet more code that is malicious.

Essentially when going over a non-secure wire, you have to keep in mind that granting an access token means that given user has rights to do actions A, B, and C on Facebook, Github, Google, your platform, etc. Anyone that grabs that token now has the same rights to do actions A, B, and C on Facebook, Github, Google, your platform, etc as the user in question.

This [article](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/03/07/oauth-authorization-attacks-secure-implementation) gives a pretty thorough understanding of the concepts behind OAuth tokens.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Great! I'm already using https because Oauth2 doesn't provide encrypting like Oauth1. Thanks! (And excelent article by the way)